# iOS collection view dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind give different class

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have custom UICollectionReusableView (with nib). As a result, I need to register nib.

```
- (void)setUpInterface {

    CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    [self.view setW:CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds)];

    [self.cvMain registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FlightDetailCollectionView" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_VIEW_HEADER];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

        FlightDetailCollectionView *headerView = (FlightDetailCollectionView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_VIEW_HEADER forIndexPath:indexPath];
//        [headerView setData:self.flightData];
        return headerView;
    }

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;
    return reusableview;

}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.cvMain.frame), 220);
}
```

I believe I am doing correctly and it indeed show my custom view. The only problem is that **dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind** give me UICollectionReusableView class and it is not my custom class. As a result, I can't even pass data to my view. How shall I do?

Comment: Did you key in that COLLECTION_VIEW_HEADER string into the nib's Identifier in storyboard?

Comment: YIk! I thought no need to set. And I have set class in that nib too. Thanks you.